# How to know what table there are in a sqlite file?

Tags: sqlite, bash, shell

I have a sqlite file but I don't know what tables there are in it and thus I can't use a SELECT query.

So, is there a way to know what table are in it ?

P.S. I am under Ubuntu Linux and I have already installed sqlite3 from shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open the database using sqlite3 using:

```
sqlite3 <databasefile>
```

Once in the sqlite3 shell you can simply type:

```
.tables
```

to see a list of all the tables.

You can see the table structure of a particular table using:

```
.schema <tablename>
```

You can also omit the table name to see the schema for the whole database.

Information about these commands and more can be seen by typing:

```
.help
```

Comment: I get this:

sqlite> .tables
Error: file is encrypted or is not a database

Comment: What does `file databasefile` say in your shell (not in sqlite)?  It should say something like "SQLite 3.x database" if it is an SQLite database.